# Can I view text files i've synced to Ubuntu One online?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am able to sync and see my file names online and on all my devices, but how can I simply view sync'd text files online, or, say, on my mobile phone (which has the Ubuntu One app installed).

Comment: AFAIK There's not a Ubuntu One file Viewer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to open the file from any device by visiting the Ubuntu One website and simply clicking the file. Also, if you want others to be able to read it, you can Publish the file. Then it'll get a normal URL that you can use to access the content.

Comment: Thanks Jo-Erlend.  But clicking on a file seems to only download it, after which one can of course view the file however one chooses.  I'm after simply viewing it online as a text file.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Well.. When you view a document in a browser, you're still downloading it first. A html document used on a web page is a text document, for instance. If it is plain text, you can probably configure your browser to display it like any web document.